# Using Hangfire with ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, hangfire

Is there a way of starting Hangfire background jobs from ServiceStack services?
I've already been able to start jobs from within MVC where I can resolve ServiceStack services but I wanted to be able to do this from within ServiceStack.

Comment: You may get more help also posting this in the [Hangfire support forums](https://discuss.hangfire.io/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some more investigation I came across this post [setup example without owin?](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/183).

One workaround would be to not install the whole Hangfire nuget package but just Hangfire.Core and Hangfire.SqlServer (or respective storage option), which requires only the reference of Owin package. The only drawback is that you cannot use Hangfire Dashboard.

Then start Hangfire and any job through the following code:

```
   JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("connection string");
   var server = new BackgroundJobServer();
   server.Start();

   RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No OWIN"), Cron.Minutely);
```

In addition you could use the ServiceStack Funq for the HangFire JobActivator:

```
JobActivator.Current = new FunqJobActivator(container);
```

after creating FunqJobActivator as follows:

```
    public override object ActivateJob(Type jobType)
    {
        var resolved = _container.TryResolve(jobType);

        if (resolved == null)
        {
            foreach (Type it in jobType.GetInterfaces())
            {
                resolved = _container.TryResolve(it);
                if(resolved != null)break;
            }
        }

        return resolved;
    }
```

Comment: I updated FunqJobActivator to support RegisterAutoWiredAs<MyType,IMyType> registration.